# jQuery - Possible to auto restripe a list after removing 1 list item between the rest?

Tags: jquery, list, refresh

I've created a multi email submission form in a scrollable div and have properly succeeded in automatically setting each email as a list item so I can zebra stripe the submission. I also can individually delete each email with a remove etc I've setup but the problem is when I delete an item the zebra stripes just mash together. How is it possible to restripe the entire list in alternating format when 1 list item is removed causing 2 like colors to stack?

I think it may be possible to achieve through the remove code because this is the motivation: (The button I've setup will remove an individual list item I choose)

```
         $(".RemoveEmailBtn").live('click', function(e) {
                $(this).closest("li").fadeOut(300, function() { 
         $(this).remove();                
       });
```

And of course just a simple line + css to create the stripe

```
 $("li.EmailList:odd").addClass("oddItem");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) remove the old styling

```
 $("li.EmailList").removeClass("oddItem");
```

2) re-stripe it

```
 $("li.EmailList:odd").addClass("oddItem");
```

Comment: Brilliant Diodeus. I went with that idea and this actually worked perfectly:
$("li.EmailList").removeClass("oddItem");
$("li.EmailList:odd").addClass("oddItem");